# Python requests returns 404 error status from today on amazon "sold by" page

Tags: python, python-requests, http-status-code-404

There

https://www.amazon.de/sp?marketplaceID=A1PA6795UKMFR9&seller=A135E02VGPPVQ&isAmazonFulfilled=1&ref=dp_merchant_link

I just can access on browser as well, but python requests returns 404 error status.

Until yesterday, this page worked as well with python requests. but from today, it does not work for me and it returns 404 error status.

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'rtt': '300',
    'downlink': '0.4',
    'ect': '3g',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ko;q=0.8',
}

response = requests.get(
    'https://www.amazon.de/sp?marketplaceID=A1PA6795UKMFR9&seller=A135E02VGPPVQ&isAmazonFulfilled=1&ref=dp_merchant_link',
    headers=headers
)
print(response.status_code) # 404
```

I really will appreciate if I can get any help from you.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine to me. Maybe you can try changing your user agent.

```
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent # fake user agent library

# random user-agent
ua = UserAgent()
user_agent = ua.random

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'rtt': '300',
    'downlink': '0.4',
    'ect': '3g',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': user_agent,
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ko;q=0.8',
}

response = requests.get(
    'https://www.amazon.de/sp?marketplaceID=A1PA6795UKMFR9&seller=A135E02VGPPVQ&isAmazonFulfilled=1&ref=dp_merchant_link',
     headers=headers
 )

print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but it still returns 404 error status.

Comment: also do you mean my init script works well on your side before you change the user-agent?

Comment: Yes indeed, it works fine before and after changing my user agent. Very strange. Are you trying to do web scraping to this website? What is the context of the request

Comment: hmm.. Odd.. why does not it work on my side..... yes, honestly, trying to scrape this page...

Comment: have you tried with another product or something?

Comment: Yep, but all don't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a **referer url in header** and generally I don't think Amazon allow scraping but use selenium if you want to scrape it easily (sure it may be overkill) but has more customization

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just added 'referer' in header, but it does not work yet. I just guess selenium will work, but it is so slow and is not my option.